# How to remove array of words from a sentence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of stop words:

`myArray = ["","a","ago","also","am","an","and","ani","ar","aren't","arent","as","ask","at","did","didn't","didnt","do","doe","would","be","been","best","better"]`

I would like to remove matching items from a sentence:

`str = 'A something and hello'`

So it becomes:

`'something hello'`

**1. How can I do that in ruby?**

**2.** How could I also do it for an array of characters (which removes all matching characters)?

Here's the array of characters:

`["(",")","@","#","^"]`

Comment: what do you want in the second case as the output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
sentence = 'A something and hello'
array  = ["","a","ago","also","am","an","and","ani","ar","aren't","arent",
          "as","ask","at","did","didn't","didnt","do","doe","would",
          "be","been","best","better"]


sentence.split.delete_if{|x| array.include?(x)}.join(' ')

 => "A something hello"
```

you might want to downcase all words before comparison, to get rid of the "A" in the beginning of the sentence:

```
sentence.split.delete_if{|x| array.include?(x.downcase)}.join(' ')

 => "something hello"
```

if you have an array of strings, it's easier:

```
(sentence.split - array).join(' ')
=> "A something hello"    #  but note that this doesn't catch the "A"
```

to also delete the special characters:

```
special = ["(",")","@","#","^"]

sentence.split.delete_if{|x| array.include?(x.downcase) || special.include?(x) }.join(' ')
```

another approach to delete words or phrases is:

```
array.each do |phrase|
  sentence.gsub!(/#{phrase}/,'')
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a similar way to do it for an array of characters also? (which removed any matching character)

Comment: @Tilo how about if I wan't remove word like "thank you" and I have in array is ["thank you", .....]

Comment: I added an example on how to do this - see end of my answer

Answer (score 1):

A one-line variant of Tilo's answer that is clean and case-insensitive (although it returns all lowercase output, which may not be ideal for all uses):

```
(sentence.downcase.split - array).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 array.map {|s| s.gsub(keyword, '')}
```

Comment: You shoudl place some descriptive text around your answer to explain what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
stop_words = ["","a","ago","also","am","an","and","ani","ar","aren't","arent","as","ask","at","did","didn't","didnt","do","doe","would","be","been","best","better"]
output = %w(A something and hello) - stop_words
```

Comment: nice, but input is supposed to be a string

Comment: also..output is supposed to be another string, not an array